# Vue.js v-show in a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm sure this one's gonna be extremely easy for you guys. I am trying to make a simple list of posts with the post titles always visible, and when you click a specific post in the list, you get the post's body. I used v-show for that. However, when I click a specific post, the bodies of all of the posts appear, instead of just the one that I clicked.

Here's the template:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h1>My Posts</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="post in list">
            <div @click="changeShow">
                <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
                <p v-show="show">{{ post.body }}</p>
                <span v-show="show" class="label label-primary">ID: {{ post.userId }}</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And the logic:

```
<script>

export default{

    data(){
        return{
            msg:'hello vue',
            list: [],
            show: false
        }
    },
    ready(){
        this.fetchPostList();
    },

    methods:{
        fetchPostList: function () {
            var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
            this.$http.get(root + '/posts').then(function (response) {
                this.list = response.data;
            })
        },
        changeShow: function () {
            this.show = !this.show;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a few ways to approach this depending on your needs.

### Multiple Open

You can make each post it's own component, that way you can have `show` be tied to each individual post instead of all of them.

```
Vue.component('post', {
  template: '#post-template',
  props: {
    post: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow() {
      this.show = !this.show
    },
  },
})
```

Then you can have use it like this:

```
<post v-for="post in posts" :post="post"></post>
```

### One Open

If you just want one open you can pass an `id` as a prop and show it based on that.

```
Vue.component('post', {
  template: '#post-template',
  props: {
    post: Object,
    selectedId: Number,
  },
  computed: {
    show() {
      return this.post.id === this.selectedId
    },
  },
})
```

Then you can do like

```
<post :selected-id="selectedId" :post="post" @click="selectedId = post.id"></post>
```

Answer (score 2):

I cheated in a different way. Just added a show property to each post and toggled that.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    list: []
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.fetchPostList()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPostList: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        this.list.push({
          title: 'First Post',
          body: 'This is the first Post',
          userId: 'Joe',
          show: false
        });
        this.list.push({
          title: 'Second Post',
          body: 'This is the second Post',
          userId: 'Joe',
          show: false
        });
        this.list.push({
          title: 'Third Post',
          body: 'This is the third Post',
          userId: 'Joe',
          show: false
        });
      }.bind(this), 2000);
    },
    changeShow: function(idx) {
      this.list[idx].show = !this.list[idx].show;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>My Posts</h1>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="post in list">
      <div @click="changeShow($index)">
        <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
        <p v-show="post.show">{{ post.body }}</p>
        <span v-show="post.show" class="label label-primary">ID: {{ post.userId }}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the method that I will give an example is not useful, but I am writing to show that there is such a way.

for example

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    isShow: false,
    postUserId: null,
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My Posts</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" v-for="post in list">
        <div @click="postUserId = post.userId; isShow = !isShow">
          <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
          <p v-show="show">{{ post.body }}</p>
          <span v-show="isShow && postUserId == post.userId" class="label label-primary">ID: {{ post.userId }}</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```