# onclick with V-for and v-if not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

im working on an project which trying to implement a list of menu with the condition on v-if statement on v-for by passing id to onclick function however its encounter an error . Kindly advise

HTML VUE：

```
<div id="app">
        <aside id="side-center">
            <ul id="asideList" class="asideList">
                <li id="nav01" v-for="items , index in ListMenu.ListMain">
                    <div class="navmenu" @click="select()">{{ items.menu_group_name}}</div>
                    <div id="side-left">
                        <ul v-if="items.id === ?">
                            <li v-for="items in ListSub1">{{items.text}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

IMAGE OF DATA :

```
ListMenu: {
                    ListMain: [
                        {
                            id:1,
                            menu_group_name: 'A',
                            ListSub1: [
                                {text: '10'},
                                {text: '100'},
                                {text: '1000'}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            id:2,
                            menu_group_name: 'B'},
                        {
                            id:3,
                            menu_group_name: 'C'},
                        {
                            id:4,
                            menu_group_name: 'D'}
                    ],
                }
```

As you can see above of the data , i was trying to onclick on the menu_group_name while trying to pass over the id on select while on the ul side you will see there is v-if statement which trying to check the id if match then display the list of ListSub1.

My script

```
selectMenu: function() {
                $("#side-left").toggle();
            }
```

How do we do this ?

Comment: did you read the vue.js documentation?

Comment: @madalinivascu I had , but i still confuse on the particular condition meet .

Comment: why are you using jquery?

Comment: i couldnt find any solution on the toggle side part

Comment: so you want to toggle the .side-left when you click .navmenu ?

Comment: @madalinivascu ya

Comment: damn hard to say so :))

Comment: a better example will be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778665/vue-js-v-show-in-a-list

Comment: @madalinivascu that example doesnt take the data  , it just writing dead of the value and pass over